# How to format current time using javascript in Selenium IDE

Tags: javascript, selenium-ide

How to get hours when `hour is < 10` append "0" to hour?

For Exemple:

`javascript{new Date().getHours() +":" + new Date().getMinutes())}` Result: 9:20...

I need to format "09:20".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var d = new Date();

console.log(
    (d.getHours() < 10 ? '0' : '') + d.getHours() + ':' +
    (d.getMinutes() < 10 ? '0' : '') + d.getMinutes()
);
```

-- you can test that in a browser & node.js console.

Or, in your syntax, I guess:

```
javascript{
    d = new Date(),
    (d.getHours() < 10 ? '0' : '') + d.getHours() + ':' +
    (d.getMinutes() < 10 ? '0' : '') + d.getMinutes()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please find below a clean solution that uses the common format tool

```
today = new Date();
var dateString = today.format("dd:mm");
alert(dateString);
```

For more details and a jsfiddle , please look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3552496/1170805)

Comment: I don't think Date.prototype.format() exists http://screencast.com/t/6hO9NZVSaRc See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/prototype

Comment: you are right Ivan, you have to add the prototype referenced in the jsFiddle.I must admit that ,if it is just for one formating operation , your solution is lighter and better.But in case you need to make more date manipulations , the prototype is broader.